# Real Time Streaming Using IMU Sensors works only when there is an interrupt from keyboarf

Tags: python

Hi I have managed to rotate an object in blender game engine by streaming values from Bluetooth IMU Sensoe
But the object rotates in real time only when there is an continuous interrupt from the keyboard. i.e constantly hold ('Ctrl+C'). When the keys are not pressed, the object doesn't rotate and is static in the environment.

Can you kindly let me know what could be wrong? 
This is my first time using Blender so any advice would be helpful. Thanks